# "I, (any name), am here to... " is this correct?

Tags: verb-agreement, personal-pronouns

I'm using this to introduce myself in a speech.

The sentence goes like, "On behalf of xyz, I, Kartik Choubisa, am here to..."
Or should i say, "... Is here to...?"

Comment: You have it right: use the first person (*am*, not *is*).

Comment: The test is to take out the name (or other "parenthetical" phrase).  You'd say "I am here to...", not "I is here to..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. It’s an example of [apposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition), typically used to clarify the identity of something by referring to it in multiple ways:

> I, Jon, like cats.
>
> Angel, my cat, is fluffy.

Be aware, though, that saying “I, (name)” sounds quite formal. It is often used to begin an oath, for example:

> I, Jon Purdy, do solemnly swear…

Ordinarily when giving a speech, an MC will introduce you to the audience, so there is no need to state your name. In that case, you can simply begin:

> MC: Please welcome Kartik Choubisa.
>
> You: Thank you. On behalf of xyz, I am here to…

Comment: +1 for "sounds quite formal". But I think it's totally inappropriate in OP's context, no matter how formal the occasion. To me, even if it's not actually a sworn oath, whatever follows *I, [my name],* has to be some kind of "momentous declaration", in the context of which the identity of the speaker must be significant. Either because "I" am already known to be important to the speech topic, or because it's some kind of "performative" speech act (such as *I, Fumbles, do **hereby** solemnly swear [blah blah]*).